# How to resolve bootloader problem in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: grub2, uefi, bootloader, dns

Yesterday, I did something that damaged the bootloader of my Ubuntu 13.04. Then I had to install Lubuntu 13.04, and I'm now using the Grub of Lubuntu. The problem is in the opening screen Ubuntu gives the following error:

```
/boot/efi not present or ready
```

Again, I can't browse the internet in that computer (my connection is manual static IP). It says:

```
name resolution failed
```

I haven't installed anything in Lubuntu, so no software is causing this problem. However I can connect to internet using another laptop. So how do fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I could suggest you remove Lubuntu and use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to restore GRUB.